# Create second resource group for nested template

Tags: json, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-resource-group

So I'm trying to deploy a template that sets up a site to site vpn and has a nested template that would setup a virtual machine connected to the azure side. Each template works by themselves as well as together when doing it as a nested template.

The problem comes in when I want to have the site to site deployed in one resource group and have the VM and related objects deployed to another resource group.

I have the following code I've put together:

```
{
        "condition": "[equals(parameters('deployVm'),'True')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups",
        "name": "[variables('deployments').resourceGroup.name]",
        "apiVersion": "2018-08-01",
        "location": "[variables('deployments').resourceGroup.location]",
        "properties": {}
    },
    {
        "condition": "[equals(parameters('deployVm'),'True')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
        "name": "[variables('deployments').name]",
        "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
        "resourceGroup": "[variables('deployments').resourceGroup.name]",
        "properties": {
            "mode": "[variables('deployments').mode]",
            "templateLink": {
                "uri": "[variables('deployments').templateLink.uri]",
                "contentVersion": "[variables('deployments').templateLink.contentVersion]"
            },
            "parameters": {}
            }
        },
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups/', variables('deployments').resourceGroup.name)]"
        ]
    }
```

Based on some other templates I've put together I don't understand why when deployed the resource group that I have set in the dependson section doesn't get created.

When I run the template azure complains that resource group "[variables('deployments').resourceGroup.name]" can't be found.

Comment: Is the deployVm parameter being properly set?

Comment: Yes but I did try running the template without the conditional lines and it still gives me the same error saying the resource group doesn't exist.

Comment: take a look at this template: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/subscription-level-deployments/create-rg-lock-role-assignment - if that doesn't help we probably need to look at the entire template to see what's going on.

Comment: That template doesn't work either, do you have access to an azure account? If you run that does it work for you cause it doesn't for me. Same error about not finding the resource group.

Answer (score 0):

The question doesnt explicitly specify this, but you need to create the resource group before hand.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-cross-resource-group-deployment#specify-a-subscription-and-resource-group

Apart from this - everything looks fine (you might want to check your `deployment` variable, which kinda looks like `deployment()` function.)

Comment: I know the resource group needs to be made before the deployment. I thought that having it in the template and making it a dependency would have it run before hand so that the group would exist.

If having that resource type in the template doesn't actually make the group then what is the point of it?

Comment: for this you need inline resource, check this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/create-resource-group-in-template#create-resource-group-and-deploy-resource. how things are setup in azure for nested deployment as a separete template resource group must exist in azure before the whole deployment starts. for inline nested deployments it appears you can do that.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that, maybe you could rephrase it.

To give you an example, if you scroll up on the link you provided there is an example template that states it can create several resource groups but if you run it it just fails and says that the resource groups were not found.

If the template doesn't make resource groups then what is it doing?

Comment: how are you deploying those templates?

Comment: Straight from the portal by making a custom template.

Comment: i dont think it works from the portal, you need to use azure cli or powershell

Comment: Of course it works from the portal, I've run tons of templates from the portal already.

Comment: cross resource group doesnt?